# IOS Deeplinking- Pass msg from email to your app

Tags: ios, deep-linking

Existing user of the app will send email to other user.

Other user may have app installed or not installed on their device. 
The email will contain some token. Now I want to pass that token to my app. I have read that by deep-linking, its possible. But how will I handle the case when other user have not installed my app yet in their IOS device.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is called Deferred Deep Linking (`Deep Linking` refers to using a link to open your app, even directly to a specific piece of content, and `Deferred` means that it works even if the app isn't installed first).

Unfortunately there's no native way to accomplish this yet on either iOS or Android. URL schemes don't work, because they *always* fail if the app isn't installed. Apple's new [Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html) in iOS 9 get closer, but you'd still have to handle redirecting the user from your website to the App Store

A free service like [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: they're so awesome I work with them) can handle all of this for you though. Here's the docs page covering exactly how to create email links like you described: https://docs.branch.io/pages/emails/email-partners-list/

Comment: No problem! Let me know if you run into any questions along the way

Comment: Tried out today. Its working like a charm, without any issue. They handle almost all cases... Wish I knew this a couple of years back... Thanks again mate! Really appreciate your help!

Comment: marketing link is not triggering app .. not able to figure out .. any suggestions ?

Comment: @RIYAZ could you post a new question with more details, or send us a [support ticket](https://support.branch.io)?

Comment: branch.io link is `404`